# C/C++/Java source code unicode character displaying in php

Tags: php, unicode, unicode-string

I have database which contains unicode character of C/C++/Java source code.
but i want my system developed in PHP.
for example: i have string of unicode `\u00c3khk\u201e\u2122r\u00d5kfk f\u00deku fku\u00bbk W\u00ed\u00c3kL\u2122 fhu Au?`
now, how to decode this string with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have got answer to decode this string.

```
$string="\u00c3khk\u201e\u2122r\u00d5kfk f\u00deku fku\u00bbk W\u00ed\u00c3kL\u2122 fhu Au?";
$string=json_decode('"'.$string.'"');

echo $string;
```

i prints original string.